# Sagemaker can't find role

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I'm new to sagemaker and I'm trying to access an S3 bucket but can't get role permissions working!

When I run the following I get the error "Couldn't call 'get_role' to get Role ARN from role name Sagemaker-DataScientist to get Role path"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the message you get if you try to call `get_execution_role()` from a notebook that's not running in sagemaker studio (i.e. on your local machine).

This api just returns a `str` so if you know it, you don't need to call `get_execution_role()`